# I want to create a button to able to TP the person pressing the button and only that person with the mods having access too

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need this done using command blocks and my knowledge on command blocks is very limited.
I need to be able to TP a specific player to their vault without anyone else gaining access except from mods.

Can anybody help?

I also need some help in setting gamemode boundries as I've looked every where online and can't find anything.

Any help would be great, plus I need it dumbing down so I can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main possibilities for you:

1. Don't distinguish them by OP/not OP, but instead `/tag` all moderators and use that in the selector in the command block.
2. Don't use command blocks at all. They are moderators, they don't need command blocks to execute commands (at least short ones). Or require something from them to activate the command block, like breaking bedrock.

Answer (score -1):

With a command block, to teleport, have the command set to `/tp @p (x) (y) (z) (Eg. /tp @p 100 4 145`) Place redstone in front of the command block, then place the block of your choice along with a button in front of the redstone.
Also for the gamemode boundaries, have another command block that is to the left or right of the redstone, and have that command set to `/gamemode @p (survival, adventure, ect) (eg. /gamemode @p survival)`

That way, when they press the button, they will teleport and their gamemode will be switched to the desired gamemode.